# Some problems about the ROS path

Tags: ros-package-path

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

My ROS has been installed at  /opt/ros/cturtles

```
/opt/ros/cturtle$ ls
```

it shows: jason  ros  setup.bash  setup.sh  setup.zsh  stacks

where the file of "jason" which I create, is to be contained myself packages.

Question1, could i create this file for including myself packages? I mean could i create this file under "cturtles" file, or "ros" file , or "stacks" file?

Question2,I create a package with 'roscreate-pkg', then I update my ros path.and the command is :

```
$ export ROS_PACKAGE_PATH=/opt/ros/cturtle/jason/:$ROS_PACKAGE_PATH
```

and then

```
$ rospack find ros_opencv   %ros_opencv is what i have created
```

but it shows
[rospack] warning: trailing slash found in ROS_PACKAGE_PATH
/opt/ros/cturtle/jason/ros_opencv

at the terminal, and the next time,I input the command

```
$ rospack find ros_opencv
```

it shows :[rospack] couldn't find package [ros_opencv]
why?

Best regards

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/9181/some-problems-about-the-ros-path/) by [Yongqiang Gao](https://answers.ros.org/users/162/yongqiang-gao/) on ROS Answers with karma: 133 on 2011-02-23

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

So it looks like you have an extra trailing slash at the end of `/opt/ros/cturtle/jason/`.  Try just using: `export ROS_PACKAGE_PATH=/opt/ros/cturtle/jason:$ROS_PACKAGE_PATH`

Also, two more things: you may want to not place your own packages in /opt/.  It may be easier permission wise to place things in say: `/home/jason/stacks`

And don't forget that you can place the export command in your .bashrc (`/home/your_name/.bashrc`) so that you don't have to type it in every new terminal you open.

---

Originally posted by [Chad Rockey](https://answers.ros.org/users/29/chad-rockey/) with karma: 4541 on 2011-02-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Thanks to chadrockey, and i have move myself files under ~/stacks,
and I also add "export ROS_PACKAGE_PATH=~/stacks:$ROS_PACKAGE_PATH" into  /.bashrc
as a results it works well.

I am new to ROS, thanks chadrockey again.

---

Originally posted by [Yongqiang Gao](https://answers.ros.org/users/162/yongqiang-gao/) with karma: 133 on 2011-02-23

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1